# nesting collectors in Java 8

Tags: java, mapreduce, java-8

I am working with demographic data. I have a collection of records about the different counties of a state (several records per county) that I want to aggregate by county.

I have implemented the following Consumer:

```
public class CountyPopulation implements java.util.function.Consumer<Population>
{
    private String countyId ;
    private List<Demographic> demographics ;

    public CountyPopulation()
    {
        demographics = new ArrayList<Demographic>() ;
    }

    public List<Demographic> getDemographics()
    {
        return demographics ;
    }

    public void accept(Population pop) 
    {
        if ( countyId == null )
        {
            countyId = pop.getCtyId() ;
        }
        demographics.add( pop.getDemographic() ) ;
    }

    public void combine(CountyPopulation other) 
    {
        demographics.addAll( other.getDemographics() ) ;
    }
}
```

This CountyPopulation is used to aggregate data about a specific county using the following code (where "089" is a county identifier):

```
CountyPopulation ctyPop = populations
    .stream()
    .filter( e -> "089".equals( e.getCtyId() ) )
    .collect(CountyPopulation::new, 
             CountyPopulation::accept, 
             CountyPopulation::combine) ;
```

Now, I would like remove the "filter" and group the records by county before using my aggregator.

Based on your first answers, I understand that this can be done using the static function Collector.of in the following way:

```
Map<String,CountyPopulation> pop = populations
    .stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Population::getCtyId,
                              Collector.of( CountyPopulation::new,
                                            CountyPopulation::accept, 
                                            (a,b)->{a.combine(b); return a;} ))) ;
```

However this code does not work because Collector.of() has a different signature than collect().
I suspect that the solution involves modifying class CountyPopulation so that it implements   java.util.function.BiConsumer instead of java.util.function.Consumer but my attempt todo so hasn't worked and I am not clear why.

Answer (score 1):

Calling [`collect` with the three arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) on a `Stream` is equivalent to use [`Collector.of`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-).

So you can achieve your goal using:

```
Map<String,CountyPopulation> pop = populations.stream().collect(
  Collectors.groupingBy(Population::getCtyId, Collector.of(
    CountyPopulation::new, CountyPopulation::accept, CountyPopulation::combine))) ;
```

For better parallel performance, it’s worth studying the optional [`Characteristics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.Characteristics.html) you can provide. If either or both of `UNORDERED` or `CONCURRENT` match the behavior of your `CountyPopulation` class, you may provide them (`IDENTITY_FINISH` is implied in your case).

And using [`groupingByConcurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingByConcurrent-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) instead of `groupingBy` may also improve parallel performance.

Comment: I must still be missing something, now Java complains about the arguments of the of method. The method of(Supplier<R>, BiConsumer<R,T>, BinaryOperator<R>, Collector.Characteristics...) in the type Collector is not applicable for the arguments (CountyPopulation::new, CountyPopulation::accept, CountyPopulation::combine)

Comment: `Collector.of` has a slightly different signature than `collect`.  The third argument to collect is a `BiConsumer`, but Collector.of requires `BiOperator`.  Replace `CountyPopulation::combine` with `(a,b)->{a.combine(b); return a;}`.  Or, alternatively, change the `CountyPopulation.combine` method to return the resulting `CountyPopulation`.

Comment: @Misha: Right, or simply said, if the semantics didn’t change, `CountyPopulation.combine` has to return `this`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally got it to work but I had to explicitly add the characteristics parameter:

```
ConcurrentMap<String,CountyPopulation> pop = populations
    .parallelStream().collect(
      Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(
          Population::getCtyId, 
          Collector.of( 
              CountyPopulation::new, 
              CountyPopulation::accept, 
              (a,b)-> {a.combine(b); return a; }, 
              Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH  ) ) )  ;
```

Comment: You don’t need to specify `IDENTITY_FINISH` if you use the three-arg method, as it is implied due to the fact that you didn’t specify a finish function. You shouldn’t need to specify obsolete characteristics; it’s a varargs method which will also accept no characteristics argument.